# The importance of using === instead of == in php!

Tags: php, comparison-operators

Today only I have noticed and found out the importance of using **===** operator. You can see it in the following example:

```
$var=0;
if ($var==false) echo "true"; else echo "false";  //prints true
$var=false;
if ($var==false) echo "true"; else echo "false";  //prints true
$var=0;
if ($var===false) echo "true"; else echo "false";  //prints false
$var=false;
if ($var===false) echo "true"; else echo "false";  //prints true
```

The question is that, are there any situations where it is important to use **===** operator instead of using **==** operator?

Comment: You could just say `echo $var == false;` etc.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117967/what-does-mean

Comment: @Chris. I have look at that question already. But my question is about examples, where it is really important to consider using "===" operator, not "==" operator.

Comment: @Skilldrick: No, you can't. PHP doesn't automatically convert boolean values to "true"/"false" strings. Your example would yield either `1` (for `true`) or the empty string (for `false`). The examples could be shortened, however, by using the ternary operator like so: `print ($var == false) ? 'true' : 'false';`.

Comment: @Jakob: fair enough! Good point.

Comment: One of my pet peeves in PHP, by the way. It makes quick-and-dirty debugging so much less quick and so much more dirty, when all you want is for `print true` to actually *print* true.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Of course, just one example: [`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

> **Warning**
>
> This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the `===` operator for testing the return value of this function.

Basically if you use any function that **returns a value on success but `FALSE` on failure**, you should check the result with `===` to be sure (otherwise why would there be a big red warning box? ;))

---

Further examples: [`next()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.next.php), [`current()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php)
or as also mentioned string functions as [`strpos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php), [`stripos()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php), etc.

Even [`substr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) although it is not mentioned explicitly:

> Returns the extracted part of string or FALSE on failure.

But what if the extracted part is`"0"`? It also evaluates to `FALSE`, but it is not an error.

Comment: `next` and `current` are not good examples. What if there are *false* values like in `array(false)`?

Comment: @Gumbo: That's right. I just mentioned them because they also have this warning box in their documentation. But there is a note (that should be more emphasized imho): *Note:  You won't be able to distinguish the end of an array from a boolean FALSE element. To properly traverse an array which may contain FALSE elements, see the each()  function.*

Answer (score 8):

Always choose `===` over `==` except you're absolutely sure you need `==`, because `==` is not transitive.  And that in turn is important for your reasoning about your code.

Consider the following code snippet

```
if ( $a == $b && $b == $c ) {
    // [1] assert: $a == $c
}
```

Anybody would infer from the if condition that the assertion `$a == $c` is true because we are so used to the equality relation being transitive.  But that doesn't hold for `==`, counter example:

```
$a = "0";
$b = 0;
$c = null;
```

Now think about how often we make (at times unconsciously) that assumption while writing code. That could lead to serious bugs.

Answer (score 6):

In [`strpos()`](https://www.php.net/strpos) you have 0 when string is found and false when is misissing. You must use `===` to check difference.

Answer (score 3):

The `===` is [***strict*** type comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) operator, it will not only check **values** but also their **type** whereas `==` only checks whether or not **values** are same.

Consider a situation when you compare *numbers or strings*:

```
if (4 === 4) // same type and value
{
  // true
}
```

but

```
if (4 == "4") // same value but different type
{
  // true
}
```

and

```
if (4 === "4") // same value but different type
{
  // false
}
```

So in above cases, you have to make sensible choice whether to use == or ===

Comment: Yeah, I knew that. But I want to find out examples where it is important to use one operator instead of another.

Comment: Look at Felix Kling's response for example. He understood what I want.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor: As you can see in my example, this is also useful when comparing numbers and strings :)

Comment: Now, I can see, but when commenting to you answer there was no examples. Thx a lot for example.

Answer (score 3):

A good example where you can get into trouble is comparing 0 and a string, fx

```
if (0 == 'completed') {
  // evaluates as TRUE
}
```

A string not starting with a number becomes `0` when converted into an int. This can become a problem when comparing a status that can be 0 to a string.

Answer (score 2):

The `===` operator checks type as well as value equality.

That's why `0 === false` does not return true, as they are not of the same type.

Answer (score 1):

strpos($needle,$haystack) and related functions will return false if $needle doesn't exist in $haystack, and 0 if $needle is the first character of $haystack; and there's a whole host of similar functions.
Using == can give you incorrect results in this case, so you should always use ===. The manual clarly identifies where this is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently ran into this problem myself when I was writing a quick SQL query parser. To cut the story short, I was comparing quoted parameters with their corner-case placeholders. Basically, the following code led me to some hard debugging times (the example is simplified of course)

```
$var = 0; // This is supplied dynamically

$someCondition = $var == '?';
```

`$someCondition` ended up being true all the time. *Shiver*

Basically any non-strict (==) <int> == <string> comparison will cause the string to be cast to an integer. Depending on the input, this might end up as 0 or the int-value of the string, if it has any, even if the whole string is not completely numeric.

Answer (score 0):

If you compare two numerical strings, they are compared as integers.[1](http://www.phpwtf.org/string-comparison)

```
var_dump("15" == "0xF"); // TRUE
var_dump("15" === "0xF"); // FALSE
```

and TRUE is indirectly equal to FALSE [2](http://www.phpwtf.org/its-quite-logical)

```
$a = 0;
$b = 'x';
var_dump(FALSE == $a); // TRUE
var_dump($a == $b);  // TRUE
var_dump($b == TRUE);  // TRUE
var_dump(FALSE === $a); // FALSE
var_dump($a === $b);  // FALSE
var_dump($b === TRUE);  // FALSE
```