# What do !== and === mean in PHP?

Tags: php, syntax, operator-keyword

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How do the equality (== double equals) and identity (=== triple equals) comparison operators differ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-compariso)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [php not equal to != and !==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and)

What are the `!==` and `===` operators in this code snippet?

```
if ( $a !== null ) // do something
if ( $b === $a ) // do something
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: It's really unfortunate that the SO search engine doesn't work for '===' because this question gets asked about once a month.

Comment: One of the best answers is provided as comment xD

Comment: @Paul There's [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-compariso) for `===` and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3641819/php-not-equal-to-and) for `!==`. This is kind of a duplicate of both; I'm voting to close as a duplicate of the first, and hopefully somebody else votes for the second so they both show up in the list (whoever voted to close as NaRQ is just lazy)

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: You must come here pretty infrequently ;)

Comment: Here is another one: [What does “===” mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117967/what-does-mean)

Comment: @Bolt, maybe I'm guilty of under-estimation.  I'm not really active in the php tag.

Comment: @Paul: \*checks your tags\* You're right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are strict type comparison operators. They not only check the **value** but also the **type**.

Consider a situation when you compare numbers or strings:

```
if (4 === 4) // same value and type
{
  // true
}
```

but

```
if (4 == "4") // same value and different type but == used
{
  // true
}
```

and

```
if (4 === "4") // same value but different type
{
  // false
}
```

This applies to objects as well as arrays.

So in above cases, you have to make sensible choice whether to use `==` or `===`

It is good idea to use `===` when you are sure about the type as well

**More Info:**

- http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 13):

They are <s>identity</s> equivalence operators.

```
1 == 1
1 == "1"
1 === 1
1 !== "1"
true === true
true !== "true"
true == "true"
```

All of these equate to true.
Also check [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) provided by @mbeckish

Comment: I wouldn't call it identity though, because two objects with a different identity can still have the same value and the same type (and be `===` equal as such). There is just no *identity* in php.

Comment: It's the equivalence operator.  It asserts that both "arguments" (left and right side) are both equal and of the same type (and if an object, the same class).

Answer (score 1):

=== also checks for the type of the variable.

For instance, `"1" == 1` returns true but `"1" === 1` returns false. It's particularly useful for fonctions that may return 0 or False (strpos for instance).

This wouldn't work correctly because strpos returns 0 and 0 == false

```
if (strpos('hello', 'hello world!'))
```

This, however, would work :

```
if (strpos('hello', 'hello world!') !== false)
```

Comment: This answer is correct, but I am going to add an example.  `strpos("abcde", "f")` returns `false`, because `f` is not in the string `abcde`.  You may want to test for this, so you would use `if (strpos("abcde", "f")===false)`.  If you simply did `if(!(strpos("abcde", "f")))` then you would be in trouble if strpos actually returned `0`.  Why?  Because PHP is loosely typed and `0`0 and `false` are equivalent when not comparing types as well.

Answer (score 0):

A double = sign is a comparison and tests whether the variable / expression / constant to the left has the same value as the variable / expression / constant to the right.

A triple = sign is a comparison to see whether two variables / expresions / constants are equal AND have the same type - i.e. both are strings or both are integers.

The same concept applies for !==

Answer (score 0):

They will only return true if both the type and value of the values given are equivalent.
Example:
1 === 1 is true
"1" === 1 is false
1 === "1" is false
"1" === "1" is true

where as with == all of the above would be true

Answer (score 0):

When you use two equal signs `==` it will check for the same value.

```
if( '1' == 1 ) { echo 'yes'; }
```

The above code works because they have the same value.

But if you use three equal signs `===` it will check the value and the data type.

Therefore

```
if( '1' === 1 ) { /* this will not work */ }
```

This is because `'1'` has a data type of `string` while `1` is an `integer` or a `number`

But you could do something like this - I think :D

```
if( (integer) '1' === 1 ) { echo 'this works'; }
```

Because we are changing the data type of `'1'` to an `integer`