# What does === mean in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “===” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117967/what-does-mean)

i am seeing === often in php statements, but don't know what it mean.
e.g if ($pwd === PwdHash($pass,substr($pwd,0,9))).
thanks

Comment: @rdlowrey: that is an auto-generated comment that appears when a vote to close is claiming the question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

It tests equality, but unlike `==` it requires that the two operands be of the same *type* as well as value.

For instance, `"1" == 1` will be true, but `"1" === 1` is false because the type is different.

Comment: The important point is not that `===` requires same type, but `==` actually attempts to perform **type casting** to make them `===`.

Comment: PHP's documentation on "Type Juggling" gets into more detail about its type system and casting (http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score -1):

php has two types of equal comparison operator `==` and `===`

`==` check for the equalization but not strict mean it will return true for ('123'==123)

`===` is a strict equal operator it will return false for the ('123'===123)

read more about these from [here](http://in.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Comment: `'abc'=='ABC'` will be `false` too

Comment: `'abc' == 'ABC'` is false because the strings are different.

Comment: thanks guys to remember my fault, I apologies for my mistake and correct that.