# The usage of == and === in php

Tags: php, comparison-operators

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does “===” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117967/what-does-mean)

I am confused with the use of those operators in php, I am not quite sure when should I use === and when ==.

for example why/when should I write:

```
if( $some_method_that_returns_something_or_false() === FALSE) {
      //do stuff
}
```

and when with ==?

Also, does === means I must return bool FALSE or I can return 0? When it is considered an bad practice to use === or ==?

Also when putting something like this:

```
 if($some_method_that_returns_true_or_false()) {

 }
```

is that $some_method_that_returns_true_or_false() == TRUE or
some_method_that_returns_true_or_false() === TRUE?

Comment: There must be 1000 dupes for this question here. Try using the search at the top right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

=== means exact value, so for true it has to be true, while == checks for the meaning of the value, so true will be also a value of '1' or a whatever String.

Comment: I see, so in essence. If I want it to be strictly bool and not for example some object etc I use ===.

Comment: Not a whatever string; `"0" != true` and `"" != true`

Answer (score 1):

`==` is used for checking equallity and `===` is used for checking the equality as well as type.

And

```
if($some_method_that_returns_true_or_false()) {

}
```

is checking for `$some_method_that_returns_true_or_false() == TRUE`