# How to hide a td when dynamically getting data in PHP codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a form displaying in a table dynamically working properly but my issue is if one field is empty in database in front end I want to hide that field.
Here is my view code:

```
<?php
         foreach($jobs as $row)
         {
              ?>
               <tr>
               <?php
               if($row->job_advantage_skills = '')
               {?>
               <td valign="middle"><strong>Advantage:</strong><?php echo $row->job_advantage_skills; ?></td>
               <?
               }
               ?>
               </tr>
           <?
            }
            ?>
```

Here I have given `if($row->job_advantage_skills = '') {}` for this I want to hide if there is advantage skills hide this field in front end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to hide the field if '`$row->job_advantage_skills`' is empty:-

So, instead of using `(= or == or ===)` you have to use `!= (not equals to)`

So, your code will be:-

```
<?php
           if($row->job_advantage_skills != '')
           {?>
               <td valign="middle"><strong>Advantage:</strong><?php echo $row->job_advantage_skills; ?></td>
           <?
           }
?>
```

OR

You can also use [ !empty() ]:-

```
<?php
               if(!empty($row->job_advantage_skills))
               {?>
                   <td valign="middle"><strong>Advantage:</strong><?php echo $row->job_advantage_skills; ?></td>
               <?
               }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in if statement Dont assign the value

use

```
    if($row->job_advantage_skills == '')

instead of

   if($row->job_advantage_skills = '')
                                ^
```

For hide

```
<tr>
               <?php
               if($row->job_advantage_skills == '')
               {?>
                      // add class for hide
               <td class="hide" valign="middle "><strong>Advantage:</strong><?php echo $row->job_advantage_skills; ?></td>
               <?
               }
               ?>
               </tr>
```

CSS

```
.hide{
display:none;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0):

you just set the value for `$row->job_advantage_skills = ""`. if check condition is null put `==` or `===`

```
if($row->job_advantage_skills == '')
```

Comment: Sorry add `===` to your answer.. Just now confirmed it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117967/what-does-mean

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `==`/`===` not `=`. Check **[php comparison operators](http://www.php.net//manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)**.
2. To hide the `<td>` use `display:none` or add a css class with `display:none` property.

---

```
<?php
if($row->job_advantage_skills == '')
{?>

   <td valign="middle" style="display:none"><strong>Advantage:</strong><?php echo $row->job_advantage_skills; ?></td>

<?
}
?>
```